# Magento Paypal Express having issues with Downloadable Products

Tags: magento, e-commerce, product

Just like to send a thanks out in advance for the help.

I have successfully setup a downloadable product with the option of filling out the URL in the Downloadable Information section. I have also successfully integrated the Paypal Express payment option. I can also successfully add the product to my cart, checkout and pay through Paypal Express from the link on my cart. I also am receiving the order email successfully. The problem comes once the download link is clicked, Magento tries to process and download but re-directs to the account login screen.

Here are a few notes:

1. Guest checkout for downloadable products is enabled.
2. System->Configuration->Catalog->Downloadable Product Information-> Order Item Status - Set to Pending (I am thinking this is the problem due to the fact that I can't change it to Complete) If you agree, please advise on the best way to accomplish this.
3. All orders are showing as Complete and PayPal is successfully capturing the monies.

Again, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Set the ***Order Item Status to enable Downloads***  to Invoiced and this fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with Magento 1.4.x that does not allow user account registration at the checkout process.  You can select register, walk through the checkout, and you'll get paid and it will all look successful and everything, but Magento will fail to create the customer account, thus making it impossible for the users to download their product.

It totally sucks.  I have a store that is useless until I can figure out how to get this fixed, as I only use the express checkout method, and all my products are downloadable.